# How to get specific column in a row (csv)

Tags: python, csv

I have this piece of code:

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        print(' '.join(row))
```

and it returns:

```
Type,UniProt ID,Position
Sodium channel,P35498,1-123
Sodium channel,P35498,176-188
Sodium channel,P35498,234-239
Sodium channel,P35498,426-762
Sodium channel,P35498,823-830
Potassium channel ATP-sensitive inward rectifier,P48048,1-77
```

I would like to be able to put `P35498` in a string to use later. How would I do this? I would also like to be able to get any of those columns but just an example with `P35498` would be great, thanks!

If I do

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    idlist = []
    for row in reader:
        idlist.append(row[1])
        print(idlist)
```

This is returned:

```
['UniProt ID']
['UniProt ID', 'P35498']
['UniProt ID', 'P35498', 'P35498']
['UniProt ID', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P35498']
['UniProt ID', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P35498']
['UniProt ID', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P35498']
['UniProt ID', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P35498', 'P48048']
```

Comment: So you want to get only the row which has `p35498`

Comment: Yes, but I would still like to print the entire row. @VigneshKalai

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, just doing

```
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        uniprot_id = row[1]
        print uniprot_id
```

works.

Comment: That code is exactly same as  - `unitprot_id = row[1]; print uniprot_id` , why you using the soooo big route?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I was going to create a list with all of the ids but I decided against it and just didn't edit it...and I put `uniprot_id_list = []` in the wrong place... thanks for reminding me, I would've actually kept it there!

Answer (score 1):

`row` is a list, you can use indexes to get the data for the corresponding column. For example for column `ID` , which is the second column , so index `1` , you would use -

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    idlist = []
    for row in reader:
        idlist.append(row[1])
    print(idlist)
```

At the end, `idlist` would be a list of all ids in the csv.

Also, according to your example , you should use `,` as the delimiter.

As said in the question comments, If the ask is to print a row with a specific id you can use -

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if 'P35498' in row[1]:
            print(' '.join(row))
```

Comment: I think the actual ID is `UniProt ID`, which is column 2, and would be index 1, so `row[1]`

Comment: Yes thanks, the delimiter according to example should be `,` not space.

Comment: @AnandSKumar correct me if I am wrong but he said all row right

Comment: @VigneshKalai Not sure i thought the ask was to get the column , but anyway added that to the answer as well. Thanks.

Comment: @AnandSKumar if you do your first answer. Look at my edit.

Comment: your indentation is wrong, in my example, `print(idlist)` is outside the for loop.

Comment: But I think I just answered my own question actually. I did not realise it was a list so that was my problem really.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the row which has "P35498" in column 2 you could check column 2 and print so when it is same :

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        if "P35498"==row[1]:
            print(' '.join(row))
```